# Optimize performance of nested GROUP BY

Tags: index, optimization, group-by, sqlite

I have a query on the table `random_numbers` with a `GROUP BY` nested inside another `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    a,
    min(x_max) AS x_minmax
FROM (
    SELECT
        a,
        b,
        max(x) AS x_max
    FROM
        random_numbers
    GROUP BY
        a,
        b
) GROUP BY
    a
```

The table `random_number` has two integer columns `a` and `b` and one floating-point column `c`:

```
CREATE TABLE random_numbers (
    a INTEGER,
    b INTEGER,
    c FLOAT
)
```

Table statistics:

- Column `a` has random integer values less than `10^5`.
- Column `b` has random integer values less than `10^6`.
- Column `c` has random floating-point values between `0` and `1`.

Thus, the table has `10^7` entries:

- `GROUP BY a, b` has approximately 10 entries per key `(a, b)`.
- `GROUP BY a` has approximately 100 entries per key `(a)`.

How do I optimize the performance of this query?
I would like to apply the solution to a MySQL database.
But my intellectual curiosity extends to other SQL databases, too. :-)

## Benchmarks

Currently, I have an index on the columns `a` and `b` of the `random_numbers` table:

```
CREATE INDEX
    ab
ON random_numbers (
    a,
    b
)
```

In SQLite, the execution plan of the query is

```
QUERY PLAN
|--CO-ROUTINE SUBQUERY 1
|  `--SCAN random_numbers USING INDEX ab
|--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

Obviously, the inner query is lightning-fast (less than a second).
The outer query is slow because it has to build the `B_TREE` on the results of the inner query (more than a minute).

Questions on my mind:

- Are there more sophisticated indices to explore?
- Is this a case for temporary tables?
- Is it actually reasonable to expect better performance?

## Supplementary material

This is my Python script used to create the SQLite database:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

import sqlalchemy as sqla

random.seed(0)

engine = sqla.create_engine("sqlite:///playground.sqlite")
metadata = sqla.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

def create_table():
    table = sqla.Table(
        "random_numbers",
        metadata,
        sqla.Column("a", sqla.Integer),
        sqla.Column("b", sqla.Integer),
        sqla.Column("x", sqla.Float),
        sqla.Index("ab", "a", "b"),
    )
    table.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)

def fill_table():
    table = metadata.tables["random_numbers"]

    PARTITION = 1000
    for i in range(int(1E7) // PARTITION):
        rows = [
            {
                "a": random.randrange(int(1E5)),
                "b": random.randrange(int(1E6)),
                "x": random.random(),
            } for _ in range(PARTITION)
        ]

        with engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(table.insert().values(rows))

        print((i + 1) * PARTITION)
```

Comment: Is it actually reasonable to expect better performance? No. You're having to read all the data and sort it, then sort that result. Your index on `(a,b)` isn't really useful - you're not filtering on those columns so the only thing it's doing is allowing the RDBMS to read your table in an order (you still need `X`), that's probably not going to help much. It will probably be faster to read the entire table once (benefiting from bulkier reads) than read it bit by bit in order of the random columns. This is something you optimize by not doing it - perhaps have precomputed table instead

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewSayer .
Turns out this was half the answer.
Someone else has brought up covering indices, which make up the other half of the full answer.
Unfortunately, they deleted their answer.
For posterity, I will post my findings as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there are two correct answers:

1. No index.
   See [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308816/optimize-performance-of-nested-group-by#comment603363_308816) by [Andrew Sayer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/217655/andrew-sayer).
2. Covering index.
   Unfortunately, they deleted their answer.
   There, I will elaborate my findings on their behalf.

## Benchmarks

I have refined my benchmarks from the original question.
The Python script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import time

import sqlalchemy as sqla

random.seed(0)

engine = sqla.create_engine("sqlite:///playground.sqlite")
metadata = sqla.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

def create_table(
    table_name: str = "random_numbers",
):
    table = sqla.Table(
        table_name,
        metadata,
        sqla.Column("a", sqla.Integer),
        sqla.Column("b", sqla.Integer),
        sqla.Column("c", sqla.Integer),
        sqla.Column("x", sqla.Float),
    )

    table.create(bind=engine)

def fill_table():
    table = metadata.tables["random_numbers"]

    PARTITION = 1000
    for i in range(int(1E7) // PARTITION):
        rows = [
            {
                "a": random.randrange(int(1E4)),
                "b": random.randrange(int(1E5)),
                "c": random.randrange(int(1E6)),
                "x": random.random(),
            } for _ in range(PARTITION)
        ]

        with engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(table.insert().values(rows))

        print((i + 1) * PARTITION)

def nested_queries():
    table = metadata.tables["random_numbers"]

    q_abc = sqla.select(
        table.c.a,
        table.c.b,
        table.c.c,
        sqla.func.max(table.c.x).label("x"),
    ).group_by(
        table.c.a,
        table.c.b,
        table.c.c,
    )
    t_abc = q_abc.cte()

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        for row_it in conn.execute("EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN " + str(q_abc)):
            print(row_it)

        tic = time.time()
        conn.execute(q_abc)
        print(time.time() - tic)

    q_ab = sqla.select(
        t_abc.c.a,
        t_abc.c.b,
        sqla.func.min(t_abc.c.x).label("x"),
    ).group_by(
        t_abc.c.a,
        t_abc.c.b,
    )
    t_ab = q_ab.cte()

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        for row_it in conn.execute("EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN " + str(q_ab)):
            print(row_it)

        tic = time.time()
        conn.execute(q_ab)
        print(time.time() - tic)

    q_a = sqla.select(
        t_ab.c.a,
        sqla.func.max(t_ab.c.x).label("x"),
    ).group_by(
        t_ab.c.a,
    )
    t_a = q_a.cte()

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        for row_it in conn.execute("EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN " + str(q_a)):
            print(row_it)

        tic = time.time()
        conn.execute(q_a)
        print(time.time() - tic)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "random_numbers" not in metadata.tables:
        create_table()
        fill_table()

    t = metadata.tables["random_numbers"]
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute("ANALYZE")
    nested_queries()

    idx = sqla.Index(
        "abc",
        t.c.a,
        t.c.b,
        t.c.c,
    )
    idx.create(bind=engine)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute("ANALYZE")
    nested_queries()
    idx.drop(bind=engine)

    idx = sqla.Index(
        "abcx",
        t.c.a,
        t.c.b,
        t.c.c,
        t.c.x,
    )
    idx.create(bind=engine)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute("ANALYZE")
    nested_queries()
    idx.drop(bind=engine)
```

The printed results are:

```
(6, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers')
(8, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
4.879260778427124
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(8, 2, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers')
(10, 2, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
(59, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(62, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
12.184722423553467
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 2')
(4, 2, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(10, 4, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers')
(12, 4, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
(61, 2, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(64, 2, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
(108, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 2')
(111, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
16.619513034820557
(7, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING INDEX abc')
0.0
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(9, 2, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING INDEX abc')
(49, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(52, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
131.1691746711731
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 2')
(4, 2, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(11, 4, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING INDEX abc')
(51, 2, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(54, 2, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
(98, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 2')
(101, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
132.78631687164307
(6, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING COVERING INDEX abcx')
0.0009453296661376953
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(8, 2, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING COVERING INDEX abcx')
(47, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(50, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
4.824275493621826
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 2')
(4, 2, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(10, 4, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING COVERING INDEX abcx')
(49, 2, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(52, 2, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
(96, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 2')
(99, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
8.86772608757019
```

## Interpretation

Here is a summary of the run times (in seconds):

|  | no index | `(a, b, c)` index | covering index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `GROUP BY a, b, c` | 4.88 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| `GROUP BY a, b` | 12.18 | 131.17 | 4.82 |
| `GROUP BY a` | 16.62 | 132.79 | 8.87 |

- The covering index gives the best results for this table and these queries.
- For a single-level `GROUP BY`, the `(a, b, c)` index is better than no index.
- For multi-level `GROUP BY`s, no index is better.

### Single-level `GROUP BY`

The execution plan without an index is

```
(6, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers')
(8, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
```

The execution plan for the `(a, b, c)` index is

```
(7, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING INDEX abc')
```

Thus, the index saves me the trouble of building a `B-TREE`.

### Multi-level `GROUP BY`

The execution plan without an index is

```
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(8, 2, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers')
(10, 2, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
(59, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(62, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
```

The execution plan for the `(a, b, c)` index is

```
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(9, 2, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING INDEX abc')
(49, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(52, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
```

When scanning the subquery, the savings of the index are outweighed by the frequent look-ups in the table.

### Covering index

The execution plan for the covering index is

```
(2, 0, 0, 'CO-ROUTINE 1')
(8, 2, 0, 'SCAN TABLE random_numbers USING COVERING INDEX abcx')
(47, 0, 0, 'SCAN SUBQUERY 1')
(50, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY')
```

The covering index combines the two advantages above, i.e. (i) no `B-TREE`, and (ii) no table look-ups.

## References

- [Index-Only Scans and Covering Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html).
- [Covering Indices](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).
- [How MySQL uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: But it must be in that order `a, b, c` otherwise the outer `GROUP BY` will not have the data in the correct order and will still require a sort. In SQL Server and PostgreSQL, you can do an index `(a, b) INCLUDE (c)` which means that the key is only over `a` and `b` but the index still covers `c`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the input. I attempted to verify your statement that the order matters. I modified the benchmark script such that `a` and `b` are essentially switched in the indices. There is no noticeable performance difference, and the query execution plans are the same. By itself, [the order of columns in a `GROUP BY` clause does not matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064677/does-the-order-of-columns-matter-in-a-group-by-clause#:~:text=No%2C%20the%20order%20doesn%27t,doesn%27t%20matter%20there%20either.).

Comment: In a single `GROUP BY` it does not normally matter. But in a multi-level grouping, you need to index the outer grouping columns first. See fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee3b80c9a160a1a8b2cf90fc42a0eaf2 the execution plan for `INDEX (b, a)` requires an extra sort. If you think about how it is grouping (using a `Stream Aggregate`) the data needs to be in order, and that can only happen for both `GROUP BY` levels if the data is sorted first by the outer grouping column(s) then by the inner.